# Shall the caller deallocate the return value of `SHCreateMemStream`?

Tags: c++, winapi

This is a dumb question, but I'm sorry I cannot find this information in [the online manual of the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream). I came from Linux realm. I'm not familiar with convention in Windows world.

All examples I found use smart pointer, e.g. `wil::com_ptr`, but GCC obviously doesn't provide those tools. Shall I call `Release` on the return value? Or leave it alone? Thanks.

Comment: The windows-provided smart pointer for COM interfaces is `CComPtr<T>`. `wil::com_ptr` seems to be an external package you need to somehow include.

Comment: @Artyer - CComPtr is not Windows-provided, it's ATL-provided, i.e.: Visual Studio-provided (you need a Visual Studio license to use it). wil on the other hand is MIT licensed https://github.com/microsoft/wil

Comment: *Shall I call Release on the return value?* - of course

Comment: If you do decide to use a smart pointer library make sure you understand its rules (see [We're using a smart pointer, so we can't possibly be the source of the leak](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091119-00/?p=15963)). Regardless of whether you use a library or not, you need to understand the ground rules: [Component Object Model (COM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) is a fairly complete introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IStream` is built on top of the classic COM `IUnknown` interface, and as such any COM interface pointer returned from a function has had `IUnknown::AddRef()` called on it, and so you must call `IUnknown::Release()` when you're done using the interface pointer or else you'll leak memory.

> GCC obviously doesn't provide those tools

Just in case you needed a reason to use `cl` on Windows and the Windows SDK, you found it.

Comment: My understanding is wil supports clang (or gcc maybe) with cl compatiblity on.